# Executing a subprocess in PyQt5 application never returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, subprocess, python-asyncio

I'm trying to execute a powershell command asynchronous in a `PyQt5` application. (Not `PySide2`). For this I'm creating a `subprocess` with `asyncio` to execute the command, and the `communicate()` function to get the output of the command.

```
process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(args)
stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
```

But, my application never goes past the `communicate()` function. Even if I encorporate a `Timer` class to cancel the process.

Firstly I made the following `temp.py` script without `PyQt5` to see if it works.

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import subprocess
from functools import partial
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
    level=logging.INFO,
)


class Timer:
    def __init__(self, timeout, callback):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("TIMER")
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._callback = callback
        self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._job())
        self.logger.info("Timer started")

    async def _job(self) -> None:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(self._timeout)
            self.logger.info("Timer expired")
            self._callback()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            self.logger.info("Timer cancelled")
            pass

    def cancel(self) -> None:
        self.logger.info("Cancelling timer")
        self._task.cancel()


async def do_your_thing():

    logging.info("start")

    cmd = "Start-Sleep -s 5; echo 'sleeping done'"

    stdout_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode="r+", delete=False)
    stderr_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode="r+", delete=False)

    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "powershell.exe",
        cmd,
        stdout=stdout_file,
        stderr=stderr_file,
        shell=False,
        startupinfo=startupinfo,
    )

    def _cancel_process(process):
        logging.info("terminating process")
        process.terminate()

    # timer = Timer(1, partial(_cancel_process, process))
    stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
    logging.info(f"after await process communicate: {stdout}\t{stderr}")

    stdout_file.seek(0)
    stdout_str = str(stdout_file.read())
    stdout_file.close()
    logging.info(f"stdout:\n{stdout_str}")
    stderr_file.seek(0)
    stderr_str = str(stderr_file.read())
    stderr_file.close()
    logging.info(f"stderr:\n{stderr_str}")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    asyncio.run(do_your_thing())
```

This works.

Without the `Timer`:

```
python temp.py 
17:09:14 - root - INFO: start
17:09:19 - root - INFO: after await process communicate: None   None
17:09:19 - root - INFO: stdout:
sleeping done

17:09:19 - root - INFO: stderr:

17:09:19 - root - INFO: done
```

With the `Timer`:

```
python temp.py 
17:10:22 - root - INFO: start
17:10:22 - TIMER - INFO: Timer started
17:10:23 - TIMER - INFO: Timer expired
17:10:23 - root - INFO: terminating process
17:10:23 - root - INFO: after await process communicate: None   None
17:10:23 - root - INFO: stdout:

17:10:23 - root - INFO: stderr:

17:10:23 - root - INFO: done
```

So, I think my problem has to be how `PyQt5` handles processes. I made this small `temp2.py` `PyQt5` application to test it out.

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import subprocess
from functools import partial
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

import qasync
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
    level=logging.INFO,
)


class Timer:
    def __init__(self, timeout, callback):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("TIMER")
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._callback = callback
        self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._job())
        self.logger.info("Timer started")

    async def _job(self) -> None:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(self._timeout)
            self.logger.info("Timer expired")
            self._callback()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            self.logger.info("Timer cancelled")
            pass

    def cancel(self) -> None:
        self.logger.info("Cancelling timer")
        self._task.cancel()


class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Start")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.btn)

    @qasync.asyncSlot()
    async def btn_clicked(self):

        await self.do_your_thing()

    @qasync.asyncSlot()
    async def do_your_thing(self):

        logging.info("start")

        cmd = "Start-Sleep -s 5; echo 'sleeping done'"

        stdout_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode="r+", delete=False)
        stderr_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode="r+", delete=False)

        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            "powershell.exe",
            cmd,
            stdout=stdout_file,
            stderr=stderr_file,
            shell=False,
            startupinfo=startupinfo,
        )

        def _cancel_process(process):
            logging.info("terminating process")
            process.terminate()
            logging.info("terminated process")

        #timer = Timer(1, partial(_cancel_process, process))
        stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
        logging.info(f"after await process communicate: {stdout}\t{stderr}")

        stdout_file.seek(0)
        stdout_str = str(stdout_file.read())
        stdout_file.close()
        logging.info(f"stdout:\n{stdout_str}")
        stderr_file.seek(0)
        stderr_str = str(stderr_file.read())
        stderr_file.close()
        logging.info(f"stderr:\n{stderr_str}")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = qasync.QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    main_window = TestWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It doesn't work. I get the following output without the `Timer`:

```
python temp2.py 
17:13:02 - root - INFO: start

# I closed the GUI
C finished at Wed Jul 15 17:13:23
```

And with the `Timer`:

```
17:14:03 - root - INFO: start
17:14:03 - TIMER - INFO: Timer started
17:14:04 - TIMER - INFO: Timer expired
17:14:04 - root - INFO: terminating process
17:14:04 - root - INFO: terminated process

# I closed the GUI
C finished at Wed Jul 15 17:14:17
```

Somehow `process.communicate()` blocks (however I can move the GUI around, so not really blocking) and never returns. I'm at a loss how to fix this. What am I doing wrong? Should I implement this another way?

Comment: Try to run the program **without** using `asyncio` (just launch the command with `proc = 
 subprocess.Popen(...)` and use `proc.communicate()` does the call ever return? Keep in mind that `communicate` waits for the subprocess to end.

Comment: @Bakuriu Will try tomorrow, thanks. It's no problem that `proc.communicate()` waits since I need the stdout from the command to go further. It just can't block the rest so that the GUI doesn't go into `not responding`. || What do you mean by `does the call ever return?`. It returns when not using `PyQt5`, it doesn't when using `PyQt5`. You can see this with the log outputs.

Comment: @Bakuriu With `subprocess.Popen()` `proc.communicate()` returns, but it blocks the main GUI and the Timer doens't work anymore. The Timer starts sleeping after `proc.communicate()` returns. Not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching subprocess altogether and started experimenting with QProcess.

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import subprocess
from functools import partial
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

import qasync
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
    level=logging.INFO,
)


class Timer:
    def __init__(self, timeout, callback):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("TIMER")
        self._timeout = timeout
        self._callback = callback
        self._task = asyncio.create_task(self._job())
        self.logger.info("Timer started")

    async def _job(self) -> None:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(self._timeout)
            self.logger.info("Timer expired")
            self._callback()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            self.logger.info("Timer cancelled")
            pass

    def cancel(self) -> None:
        self.logger.info("Cancelling timer")
        self._task.cancel()


class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Start")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.btn)

    def btn_clicked(self):

        self.do_your_thing()

    def proc_finished(
        self, process: QProcess, exit_code: int, exit_status: QProcess.ExitStatus
    ):

        logging.info(f"Proces finished: {exit_code}\t{exit_status}")
        logging.info(f"{process.readAllStandardOutput()}")
        logging.info(f"{process.readAllStandardError()}")

    def proc_error(self, error: QProcess.ProcessError):

        logging.info(f"Proces error: {error}")

    def do_your_thing(self):
        def _cancel_process(process):
            logging.info("terminating process")
            process.kill()
            logging.info("terminated process")

        logging.info("start")

        cmd = ["Start-Sleep -s 1; echo 'sleeping done'"]
        shell = "powershell.exe"

        process = QProcess(self)
        process.finished.connect(partial(self.proc_finished, process))
        process.errorOccurred.connect(self.proc_error)

        process.start(shell, cmd)
        Timer(2, partial(_cancel_process, process))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = qasync.QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    main_window = TestWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or if you want to wait in the same function till the process finishes

```py
    async def do_your_thing(self):
        def _cancel_process(process):
            logging.info("terminating process")
            process.kill()
            logging.info("terminated process")

        logging.info("start")

        cmd = ["Start-Sleep -s 1; echo 'sleeping done'"]
        shell = "powershell.exe"

        process = QProcess(self)
        process.finished.connect(partial(self.proc_finished, process))
        process.errorOccurred.connect(self.proc_error)

        process.start(shell, cmd)
        Timer(2, partial(_cancel_process, process))

        while process.state() != QProcess.NotRunning:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

        timer.cancel()
        if process.exitCode() == 0:
            stdout = process.readAllStandardOutput()
            logging.info(stdout)
```